# connectionString parameter missing from <profile><provider><add>?

Tags: asp.net

I do not see any parameter to specify connection string in the profile providers section of web.config file. Screenshot below -

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since not all profile providers use a connection string, it doesn't have to be present and intellisense knows that. AS you can see in the [profile section docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.profilesection(v=vs.85).aspx), it's there but not in all cases. I think it was intentionally left out of the schema to avoid confusion for cases where non-db based providers are used.

Comment: Hi Mark, If I not missing anything, in the link which you shared, I see connectionString as "LocalSqlServer" defined for <profile> <providers>. Not sure what you are referring by "all" cases. Also, do you mean it is supported but just doesn't have intellisense support?

Comment: Different providers have different options. Some don't use the connectionstring at all. The intellisense is based on an xml schema, and some items have only minimal schema definitions since the providers can be very broad and some options only relate to very particular providers.